# I want solution of left join to improve stored procedure result

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, query-optimization

I want to optimize stored procedure. Please provide suggestions how to improve.

There are 4 left joins, and it takes too much time.

There are more than 10 million rows in `t1` table. I want to group by month and filter of other relationship.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @v1 datetime
declare @v2 datetime
declare @v3 int = null
declare @v4 varchar(max)
declare @v5 varchar(max)
declare @v6 varchar(max)
declare @v7 varchar(max)
declare @v8 varchar(max)
declare @v9 int

set @v1 = @iv1
set @v2 = @iv2
set @v3 = @iv3
set @v4 = @iv4
set @v5 = @iv5
set @v6 = @iv6
set @v7 = @iv7
set @v8 = @iv8

select 
    Month(a.c1) as 'Month',
    sum(a.c2) as 'PaidAmount',
    count(a.c3)*2.5 as 'TransactionFee'
from 
    t1 a
left join 
    t2 b on a.c1 = b.c1
left join 
    t3 f on b.c2 = f.c2
left join 
    t4 c on a.c3 = c.c3
left join 
    t5 g on a.c4 = g.c4
where 
    a.c4 >= @v1 
    and a.c5 <= @v2
    and a.c6 > 0
    and a.c7 is not null 
    and a.c8 is not null 
    and a.c9 is not null
    and (@v3 is null or b.c10 = @v3)
    and (@v4 is null or CHARINDEX(','+CAST(c.c7 as varchar(max))+',',@v4) >  0)
    and (@v5 is null or CHARINDEX(','+CAST(a.c8 as varchar(max))+',',@v5) > 0)
    and (@v6 is null or CHARINDEX(','+CAST(a.c9 as varchar(max))+',',@v6) > 0)
    and (@v7 is null or CHARINDEX(','+CAST(c.c11 as varchar(max))+',',@v7) > 0)
    and (@v8 is null or CHARINDEX(','+CAST(g.c12 as varchar(max))+',',@v8) > 0)
group by 
    Month(a.c1)
```

Comment: "Give me Improvement Idea and suggestion." sounds like an order, not a question. How do you suppose we give you advise on performance? We know nothing of your system!

Comment: "Give us table specification! Give us what you tried so far!"

Comment: @Tyron78 in table t1 there are more than 10 million records and 20+ columns. table t1 is claim list. I want count, sum other aggregate group by months.

Comment: @NiravPatel just for curiosity: did you try to execute your query with fixed values instead of the variables? I experienced huge performance problems before, since the optimizer is a bit bitchy about the usage of variables within queries... might be worth a try (as first approach).

Comment: Have you looked at the **actual execution plan** ? What does it tell you? What is the **table structure** - and which **primary key** does each of your table have? Are the foreign key columns **properly indexed**?

Comment: @marc_s Yes all table have primary key. and Primary key is in relationship with main table in. All Foreign key column indexed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare @v1 datetime
    declare @v2 datetime
    declare @v3 int = null
    declare @v4 varchar(max)
    declare @v5 varchar(max)
    declare @v6 varchar(max)
    declare @v7 varchar(max)
    declare @v8 varchar(max)
    declare @v9 int
    set @v1 = @iv1
    set @v2 = @iv2
    set @v3 = @iv3
    set @v4 = @iv4
    set @v5 = @iv5
    set @v6 = @iv6
    set @v7 = @iv7
    set @v8 = @iv8

select Month(a.c1) as 'Month',
sum(a.c2) as 'PaidAmount',
count(a.c3)*2.5 as 'TransactionFee'
from 
t1 a WITH(NOLOCK)
FULL join t2 b WITH(NOLOCK) on a.c1 = b.c1 
INNER join t4 c WITH(NOLOCK) on a.c3 = c.c3
INNER join t5 g WITH(NOLOCK) on a.c4 = g.c4
INNER join t3 f WITH(NOLOCK) on b.c2 = f.c2
where a.c4 >= @v1 
and a.c5 <= @v2
and a.c6 > 0
and a.c7 is not null 
and a.c8 is not null 
and a.c9 is not null
and (@v3 is null or b.c10 = @v3)
and (@v4 is null or CHARINDEX(','+CAST(c.c7 as varchar(max))+',',@v4) > 0)
and (@v5 is null or CHARINDEX(','+CAST(a.c8 as varchar(max))+',',@v5) > 0)
and (@v6 is null or CHARINDEX(','+CAST(a.c9 as varchar(max))+',',@v6) > 0)
and (@v7 is null or CHARINDEX(','+CAST(c.c11 as varchar(max))+',',@v7) > 0)
and (@v8 is null or CHARINDEX(','+CAST(g.c12 as varchar(max))+',',@v8) > 0)
group by Month(a.c1)
```

Comment: And could you please **EXPLAIN** in plain English **WHAT** you've done and how this is supposed to improve the performance?? Please don't just dump an ever bigger slab of code on us without any explanation.....

Comment: Left join Always performance issue  because of  index scanning so i found t1 table as filter condition(index seek)  and  has relation with other tables  so i used Full join  for table t2 instead of left join  with (NOLOCKS) hints .